# Searching a Binary Search Tree - Array Based

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search-tree

I am trying to search for a word using a key value recursively. In retrieve function:
Problem is the index goes from 0, 1,3,7, to 15.... it suppose to go 0,1,3,7,8 and so forth
I have the insert working as expected. I have the inorder, preorders, all working. Can someone please help me figure out this problem? I have been working on this for 4 days now! I understand it goes left to right. Problem is it wont go right after left.
I will only add the functions and code i think you will need to help me.. I am using 2 retireve for doing a recursive..

```
bool BST::retrieve(const char *key, data& aData) const
{

retrieve(key, aData, parent);

if (key == aData)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}

}
```

the other retrieve

```
bool BST::retrieve(const char *key, data &aData, int parent) const
{


if (!items[parent].empty )
{

    if (key == items[parent].instanceData.getName())
    {
        aData.setName(key);
        return true;
    }
    else if (key < items[parent].instanceData.getName() ) // changed -- now goes from 0,2,6 suppose to go to o,2,5
    {
        parent =(2*parent) + 1;
        retrieve(key, aData, parent);
    }
    else
    {
        parent =( 2*parent) + 2;
        retrieve(key, aData, parent);
    }
//  return 0;

} 
}
```

==operator function..

```
bool operator== (const data& d1, const data& d2)
{

return strcmp(d1.getName(), d2.getName()) == 0;

}
```

and here is one of my header files..

```
 #include "data.h"

 class BST                               
 {
 public:
BST(int capacity = 5);              // constructor (default if no arg supplied)
BST(const BST& aTable);             // copy constructor
~BST();                             // destructor

void insert(const data& aData);     
bool remove(const char *key);
bool retrieve(const char *key, data& aData) const;
void displayArrayOrder(ostream& out) const;     
void displayPreOrder(ostream& out) const;
void displayInOrder(ostream& out) const;
void displayPostOrder(ostream& out) const;
int getSize(void) const;

    private:

  int size;
  int maxsize;  
  int parent;


  void expand();

struct item
{
    bool    empty;
    data instanceData;
    bool  isLeaf;
};

item *items;

void insert(int index, const data & aData ); 
void displayHeaders(ostream& out)const;
void BST::displayPreOrder(std::ostream &out, int parent)const;
void BST::displayInOrder(std::ostream &out, int parent)const;
void BST::displayPostOrder(std::ostream &out, int parent)const;
bool BST::retrieve(const char *key, data& aData, int parent) const;
void itemsPrinted(ostream &out,int size)const;
  };


 #endif // BST_H
```

part of the main() function..

```
database.insert(data("Ralston, Anthony"));
database.insert(data("Liang, Li"));
database.insert(data("Jones, Doug"));
database.insert(data("Goble, Colin"));
database.insert(data("Knuth, Donald"));
database.insert(data("Kay, Alan"));
database.insert(data("Von Neumann, John"));
database.insert(data("Trigoboff, Michael"));
database.insert(data("Turing, Alan"));
displayDatabase(true);
    retrieveItem("Trigoboff, Michael", aData);
retrieveItem("Kaye, Danny", aData);    // calls search function..
```

and

```
bool operator< (const data& d1, const data& d2)
{

return strcmp(d1.getName(), d2.getName()) < 0;


}
```

Comment: Why not just use std::multiset?  Oh, wait, is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

> it suppose to go 0,1,3,7,8

Why are you expecting this behaviour? That's not a "binary" search at all. The left child of 7 will be 15, the right child will be 16. 8 is the right child of 3.

Your code looks correct. Your results look correct. It's your expectations that appear flawed.

Comment: my tree has names in index 0,1,2,3,5,7,8,12,17

Comment: So what's the problem? You've searched the nodes you need to search and found nothing. It *should* terminate the search there, not waste time checking each and every node when we already know it won't find anything.

Comment: since 15 is empty it exits the function. =( if i take out the check for empty it just goes from 15 to 31,63,127, 256 .. etc..

somethings not right! =(

Comment: it is not checking all the nodes in the tree.. it is suppose to find a match.

Comment: The whole point of a binary search is that *you don't need to check all the nodes in the tree*. If your search is going down the wrong paths, that's because the tree isn't sorted correctly.

Comment: Well, i am getting all the required outputs(array order, preorder,inorder,postorder) correctly like i am suppose to. I was having this same problem when i was adding.

Comment: If you're expecting the function to return a boolean value indicating success, you'll need to put a `return` statement in front of the recursive calls. Also, when you test this, what node is the matching key supposed to be in?

Comment: it is suppose to be in node 5.

Comment: Then, as I said, your tree isn't sorted correctly. It should be going 0->2->5. What comparator function are you using?

Comment: When it added it added in this order. 0,1,3,7,8,17,2,5,12
i dont know if it added incorreclty because i  have a sheet that shows the order i am suppose to have. for array order, preorder, inorder,postorder. and their leafs and i have all that correctly. Would that be right even if i added incorrectly?

Comment: the comparator function i am using is above in the code i provided..

like:
bool operator== (const data& d1, const data& d2)
{

return strcmp(d1.getName(), d2.getName()) == 0;

}

Comment: That does not define what `<` or `>` means. Without a proper (and consistent) implementation of those, you're not going to get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to add that! i just added that to the bottom off all the code above..

Comment: It looks like your test it supposed to fail. There is no "Kaye, Danny" added to the tree.

Comment: anon, i forgot to add that in here. It was in the code. So, no worries there. I changed the code above in the retrieve.
else if (key < items[parent].instanceData.getName() )

Now, it goes friom 0,2,6 - I dont understand. It suppose to go from 0,2,5 like you said..

Comment: If you dump the array, what order are they in?

Comment: Anon, i fixed the problem.. It was in the else if (key < items[parent].instanceData.getName() ) i cahnged it to key < items[parent].instanceData 
The ==operator takes instanceData and uses the .getName method which returns name it does work now.. Thank you Anon for spending the time helping me. –